# Finding how much CPU a Docker container has access to from within the container

Tags: docker

Is it possible from within the Docker container to inspect how much CPUs it has access to? Let us assume that the `docker run` command that started the container may or may not have given the relevant flag(s).

My OS/distro of interest for the container is Ubuntu, but I'm also curious to know if different OSes have different means to address it.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Or is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: Travis CI users want to know. I'm somewhat certain that this kind of introspection is not possible, but I am mostly curious at this point. https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8303

Comment: Edited the title so that it is a little clearer what I am asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
DOCKER STATS
```

Docker stats command will give details of resource usage for each running container

Comment: `docker stats` does not give you the _limits_, does it? Furthermore, the `docker` command is not available from the container, unless you install Docker inside the container.